# Reduced Mana reserved - how does it work?

Tags: path-of-exile

How much mana will "Reduced Mana reserved" reduce from Spells that reserve Mana?

Here is what I mean: http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Reduced_Mana_Reservation
An Example is Sovereignty: http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Sovereignty
Putting points into it nets you 14% reduced mana reserved.

Let's say we have 10% reduced mana reserved

When you cast Purity of Lightning: http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Purity_of_Lightning
Which reserves 40% mana.

By how much will it reduce the reservation?

- by -10% additive result: 30% mana reserved
- by -10% multiplicative result: 36% mana reserved

Incase it was additive: How does it work with a second aura? 
Let's say #2 is 20% mana reservation

- -10% of 40%: 30% mana, and 20% from the other, result: 50% mana reserved
- -10% of 40%: 30% mana, and -10% of 20%: 10% mana, result: 40% mana reserved

Answer (score 3):

Reduced mana reserved can be tricky. You can try out this [Reduced Mana Reserved Calculator](http://fogz.mine.nu:8080/poe_reserved_calc/) to get a better understanding of how the math is applied.

In short, it takes the amount of mana set to be reserved (10% of your total) and chips away a subpercentage. But some things might not be as you would expect.

Here is a practical example:

> I have 41% reduced mana reserved passives from the tree. I have a lvl
>   17 reduced mana gem, which gives me a 0.74 mana multiplier on the
>   reservation. I want to know the exact calculation how much percentage
>   a 60% and 40% is going to reserve.
>
> So far i expected it to be: 60% * 0.59 * 0.74 = 26.196, which seems to
>   be wrong.
>
> I checked the source code of the mana reservation site linked before:
>   http://fogz.mine.nu:8080/poe_reserved_calc/
>
> There, you can see that they first multiply the aura reservation with
>   the mana multiplier of the gem and then round down:
>
> 60%*0.74=44.4% -> 44% reserved 40%*0.74=29.6% -> 29% reserved
>
> Then this reservation is multiplied with the passives and rounded up:
>
> 44%*0.59=25.96% -> 26% reserved 29%*0.59=17.11 -> 18% reserved
>
> This seems to be the correct calculation.
>
> Assuming this is correct, it is funny, because you actually need a
>   level 20 reduced mana and at least 0.41% reduced mana reservation
>   passives to rock four 60% auras on mana, which is exactly what I
>   hope to achieve.

Comment: Why is there no absolute value in the calculator? Like Clarity: pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Clarity It reserves 500 mana on level 20 unrelated to the actual mana. Are the roundings perhaps a bug in the game? (i know it doesn't belong here, but they are silly from my pov)

Comment: Well, I guess only the calculator developers can answer that :]

Comment: True. But is clarity as an example for absolute values affected aswell?

Comment: selfanswer: clarity is affected.